# MySQL select count of distinct values into seperate columns

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, distinct

I want to get the count of rows for each distinct value in column A grouped by column B like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| B | AValue1 | AValue2 | Avalue3 | AValue4 | ......  |
------------------------------------------------------
|B1 |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |
|B2 |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |
|...|    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

x being the different counts.
Right now i am getting basically the same data using "Group By(A,B)"
but it is in the form:

```
----------------------------------------------
| A         |    B     |   Count             |
----------------------------------------------    
| AValue1   | BValue1  |     x               |
| ...       | ....     |     x               |
----------------------------------------------
```

after which i have to transform the Data in PHP or on the client in Javascript.
The only way i could come up with to get the first table would be to do a subquery select for each of the values in A, but that defeats the purpose of it being a simpler and cleaner solution. 
Is there an easy way to achieve this in SQL or is transformation of the Group By table the best approach? Thanks in Advance

Comment: So if `A` column has a thousand distinct values, you will want a thousand columns?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: @BeetleJuice theoretically yes, although in this case i can be sure that the column will ever only have somewhere around 30 distinct values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GolezTrol's comment pointed me in the right direction. MySQL sadly doesnt have PivotTables, but i managed to solve it using the following group concat statement:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(IF(B = ''',
      B,
      ''', 1, 0)) AS `',
      B,
      '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM table
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT A, ', @sql, ' FROM table GROUP BY A');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```